# How to download a file uploaded on google cloud storage instead of viewing it?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs, href

I upload a file on google cloud storage and sends the url to an `ejs` file in which i assign its url to a button. When i click on the button, I want to download the file instead of viewing it in browser. How can i make it possible?

Ejs file code

```
<div class="send-btn-container">
    <a
        href="<%= downloadLink %>"
        download
        target="_blank"
        type="application/octet-stream"
    >Download file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

As of late 2018, clicking the link won’t trigger a download if the resource to be downloaded wasn’t served from the same origin or same server so to say. Apparently, this restriction is a security measure.

I am using my react code as example to show you a way to download a file from GCloud storage.

```
    const download = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Remote URL for the file to be downloaded
        const url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...';
        const filename = "mypdf.pdf";
  
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.blob())
          .then((blob) => {
            const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = blobURL;
            a.style.display = 'none';
    
            if (filename && filename.length) a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
   <a onClick={(e) => download(e)}>
      Download file
   </a>
```

convert into a blob URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this in regard to HTML5. If you want the file to be downloaded instead of viewing it, you can add `download` attribute to `<a>` tag as follows:

```
<a  href="downloadLink.pdf"
        download="mypdf.pdf" <!-- This will force download the file -->
        target="_blank"
        type="application/octet-stream" </a>
```

In this case, the file `downloadLink.pdf` will be downloaded as `mypdf.pdf` but this attribute is currently supported in chromium browsers only.

Comment: This is also not working. I have tried this in chrome and edge

Comment: In my case, it's working as per https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download#:~:text=Chrome%20now%20supports%20the%20HTML,rather%20than%20navigating%20to%20it.

Comment: The example they have put is also not working in my chrome browser, it is showing the image and not downloading it.