# How to direct download the file hosted on google cloud storage example - https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucketname}/file.pdf

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I have a long Google Cloud storage URL placed on a button. So when a user clicks on this button it should directly download the URL. I don't want to open the URL in a new tab.

Url will look something like this -

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/{BUCKET NAME}/FILENAME.pdf?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=&X-Goog-Date=&X-Goog-Expires=&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=
```

Comment: What is your code for the button?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457151/how-to-download-a-file-uploaded-on-google-cloud-storage-instead-of-viewing-it) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620689/instead-of-downloading-files-are-opening-in-browser) which might help

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 doesn't allow direct download of resources from different origins (resources not on the same domain).

In other words, https://yourdomain.com cannot download files from https://google.com using the HTML anchor tag.

One workaround is to fetch the resource, convert it to a blob then set the *href* to the blob URL.

Here is a code reference that does just that:

```js
/**
 * This is a workaround to download a remote file
 * @param `url` Remote URL for the file to be downloaded
 */
function Download({ url, filename }) {
   const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const download = (url, name) => {
    if (!url) {
      throw new Error("Resource URL not provided! You need to provide one");
    }
    setFetching(true);
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        setFetching(false);
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = blobURL;
        a.style = "display: none";

        if (name && name.length) a.download = name;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
      })
      .catch(() => setError(true));
  };

  return (
    <button
      disabled={fetching}
      onClick={()=> download(url, filename)}
      aria-label="download gif"
    >
      DOWNLOAD
    </button>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You can learn more here:

https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa

Comment: Not working this is the sample url - https://shorturl.at/iLZ29  I have added the shorturl because StackOverflow chars limit is getting exhausted. Once you click this short URL you will get the long URL. I need to download that file. Please help urgently